# w3c validator invalid error

Tags: html, validation, w3c

What does it mean when it says:

"Error Line 237, Column 6: document type does not allow element "BODY" here "

This is the link: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.0arrays.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&No200=1&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1#line-237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means no `body` allowed in `HTML 4.01 Frameset`. Try to correct the `DOCTYPE` to point to the document type you needed. [Choosing a DOCTYPE](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `body` tag in your HTML, even though you're using a `Frameset` DTD. You probably don't want the `Frameset` DTD, because you're not actually using frames.

See [this article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/frames/f/bl_faq4-4.htm) for more information.

Comment: Oh? I though I needed it because tumblr adds an extra iframe.

Comment: @jonnnnnnnnnie frameset is for traditional frames, not iframes. Btw, how do you remember your username?